# Що таке "вирій", та чому "птахи летять у вирій"? Яке походження цього вислову?

Tags: фразеологізми, етимологія

Восени у народі кажуть, що зимувати "птахи летять у вирій". Що є таке той "вирій", та чому туди відправляються зимувати птахи? Чи так можна казати про всіх птахів?

Чи можуть літати у "вирій" не тільки птахи? Наприклад, чи можу я сказати, що літаки чи хмари полетіли у вирій.

Чому так кажуть? Звідки пішов цей вислів (чи є він унікальним в українській культурі та чи є альтернативи в інших культурах)? Яка його історія?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cловник-довідник пана Жайворонка „Знаки української етнокультури“:

> 1. **теплі країни, краї**; також теплі води; слово (давнє «ірсад») означає «теплий край», можливо, від грецьк. «ір» — «весна»; за повір’ям, вирій пов’язаний з раєм, теплою, вічнозеленою й сонячною краї­ною, розташованою далеко на Сході, за морем, куди на зиму від­літають птахи, а на Здвиження ні­бито уповзають туди до своєї мате­рі й плазуни […]
> 2. (з великої літери) Ви́рій = Ура́й — у східнослов’янській міфології — **стародавні назви раю** — блаженної сторони, вічної весни, вічного світла і Райського (Світо­вого) дерева, Дерева життя, біля вершини якого нібито мешкають птахи та душі померлих
>
> *[… → на UkrLit: детальніше, а також словники СУМ-11, Грінченко.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9)*

Це підтверджує й ЕСУМ в 6 томах:

> **[ви́рій](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=380)**, [*вира́й, ви́рей* Пі, Ж, *ви́рʼє* Бі, *ира́й* Ж, *ирі́й* Ж, *ірʼє* Бі, *і́рій* Ж], [*и́риця*] «пташка, що повернулася з вирію»
>
> російська *и́рий*, білоруська *вы́рай*, др. *ирии*, польська wyraj
>
> загальноприйнятої етимології не має; можливо, повʼязане з псл. *jarь «весна», що разом з гот. jer «рік» походить від індоєвропейської *i̯ǒr- із ступенем чергуванням i̯ər-, звідки виникло īr-, представлене в др. *-ии*; українська форма з початковим **в** виникла внаслідок злиття прийменника *в* з іменником у сполученні *в ирій* (куди?); форми *ви́рай, ира́й* під впливом *рай*;
>
> *[… → далі](/a/3076/585)*

Думаю, сказати, що літаки чи хмари летять у вирій, можна тільки у певних випадках (наприклад, порівнюючи літак чи хмару з пташкою), але загалом таке речення можуть і не зрозуміти. Можу уявити собі якесь поетичне речення типу „Літак, як той птах, полетів кудись за обрій... Мабуть, у вирій“ абощо, але не можу уявити собі просто обрубане речення „Літак/хмара полетів/ла у вирій“.