# Як виникло слово "Вирій"?

Tags: етимологія, соціолінгвістика

У словниках є визначення слова, проте я не знайшла його походження.
Вирій - це теплі краї в які відлітають птахи.  Мене цікавить походження та лексема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> У нас є схоже питання з відповіддю: [Що таке “вирій”, та чому “птахи летять у вирій”? Яке походження цього вислову?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/240/)

Питання про походження слова «вирій» доволі складне й неоднозначне. Це слово дуже давнє, має багато нашарувань з різних мов, культур, та релігій, через питання його походження на форумах часто виникають епічні побоїща. Тому я просто залишу тут статтю про це слово із [етимологічного словника української мов](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm)и у 7 томах, [том 1](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.djvu), сторінка 380:

> **[ви́рій](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=380)**, [*вира́й, ви́рей* Пі, Ж, *ви́рʼє* Бі, *ира́й* Ж, *ирі́й* Ж, *ірʼє* Бі, *і́рій* Ж], [*и́риця*] «пташка, що повернулася з вирію»
>
> російська *и́рий*, білоруська *вы́рай*, др. *ирии*, польська wyraj
>
> загальноприйнятої етимології не має; можливо, повʼязане з псл. *jarь «весна», що разом з гот. jer «рік» походить від індоєвропейської *i̯ǒr- із ступенем чергуванням i̯ər-, звідки виникло īr-, представлене в др. *-ии*; українська форма з початковим **в** виникла внаслідок злиття прийменника *в* з іменником у сполученні *в ирій* (куди?); форми *ви́рай, ира́й* під впливом *рай*; заслуговує на увагу також спроба повʼязання з прус. iuriay «море» (Мартынаў Белар. лінгв. 7, 69); менш задовільні інші пояснення: як запозичення з іранської мови, — пор. ір. airyā- «арійська країна» ([Фасмер-Трубачев 2 137—138](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&first=1&off=&text_word=&method_word=substring&ic_word=on&text_general=&method_general=substring&ic_general=on&text_origin=&method_origin=substring&ic_origin=on&text_trubachev=&method_trubachev=substring&ic_trubachev=on&text_editorial=&method_editorial=substring&ic_editorial=on&text_pages=2,137-138&method_pages=substring&ic_pages=on&text_any=%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9&method_any=substring&sort=word&ic_any=on)); як повʼязаного з ос. ir (iræ) «осетини» (Vasmer RSI 6, 176—177; Филин Образ. яз. 279), з іменником *рай* (Brückner 452), з псл. *virъ «вир» (Toivonen FUF 24, 104—126), з грецької ἔαρ (ἦρ) «весна» (Горяев 123; Преобр. 1 273), з дінд. araṇyaḥ «чужий, далекий» і з лит. óras «повітря» (Потебня РФВ 6, 146, 155) та ін.
>
> Ильинский РФВ 74, 138—140; Филин Происх. яз. 529—530;  ЭСБМ 2 279—280; Топоров 3 95—56.

Оскільки «Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 т. є найкращим джерелом даних про походження українських слів, а вас ця тема цікавить, просто скачайте всі 7 томів, вони маленькі, і тоді одразу самотужки зможете знаходити відповіді на подібні питання.